# Using a Variable from a Javascript Function

Tags: javascript

OK, I'm fairly new to javascript and am trying to make this script work. I don't know the terms of javascript enough to search for this I guess because it seems like a fairly easy thing to do, but it is not working. The links are supposed to open a side menu that slides across the screen and displays different data depending on which link is clicked.

```
My Script: 
/* Open the sidenav */
 function openNav(boxid) {
   document.getElementById(boxid).style.width = "100%";
 }

/* Close/hide the sidenav */
 function closeNav() {
   document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
 }


My Body:   
    include('dbconn.php');

    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM joblist';
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo '<span onclick="openNav(mySidenav-            '.$row['jobname'].')">'.$row['jobname'].'</span><br>';
        echo '<div id="mySidenav-'.$row['jobname'].'" class="sidenav">';
        echo '<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn"       onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>';
        $eachrow = explode("," , $row["itemlist"]);

    $arrlength = count($eachrow);
        for($x = 0; $x < $arrlength; $x++) {
            echo $eachrow[$x];
            echo "<br>";
        }
        echo "</div>";

    }
```

I'm not sure why boxid isn't sending the variable I place in each onclick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at what you're doing:

```
echo '<span onclick="openNav(mySidenav-            '.$row['jobname'].')">'.$row['jobname'].'</span><br>';
```

That'll generate some html that looks like

```
<span onclick="openNav(mySidenav-         jobname)">jobname</span><br>
```

That opennav call is doing a mathematical subtraction of two undefined variables, and sending the result of that undefined operation as an argument to the function.

You probably want something more like:

```
 echo '<span onclick="openNav(\'mySidenav'.$row['jobname'].'\')">'.$row['jobname'].'</span><br>';
                              ^^----------------------------^^
```

Note the extra (escaped) quotes, which now produces

```
<span onclick="openNav('mySideNav-jobname')">jobname</span><br>
```

Now your argument is a string, not a math operation.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know it would make it a mathematical equation by adding the -